# Convert GeoJson with CRS "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" to Google Map lat/long

Tags: google-maps, geometry, kml, geojson, ogr

Currently I am looking a solution to convert geojson file to correct lat-long on google map as below:

**well.geojson:**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "WDB_ID": 1,
                "SRC_DATA": "RDI DWQI Database",
                "STD_WELL_I": "RDI_DWQI_1",
                "OTH_WELL_I": null,
                "PROVINCE": "Kampong Cham",
                "DISTRICT": "Batheay",
                "COMMUNE": "Batheay",
                "VILLAGE": "Batheay",
                "VILLAGE_ID": 3010102,
                "CONDITION": null,
                "CONT_NAME": null,
                "CONT_PHONE": null,
                "CONT_QUAL": null,
                "CONT_SECT": null,
                "FACILITY": "School",
                "FACILITY_N": "Unknown",
                "OWNER_NAME": null,
                "OWNER_PHON": null,
                "WGS_E": 494022,
                "WGS_N": 1326178,
                "MSL_APPROX": 9,
                "WELL_TYPE": "Drilled Well",
                "DRI_END_DA": "01-Jan-06",
                "DRI_TOT_DE": 36.0,
                "PUMP_INSTA": "Unknown",
                "PUMP_TYPE": null,
                "PUMP_MODEL": null,
                "PUMP_INST_": null,
                "PUMP_DEP_M": null,
                "PUMP_YIEL_": null,
                "PUMP_RIS_M": null,
                "COORD_SRC": "DATABASE",
                "water qual": "RDI DWQI Database",
                "water qu_1": "RDI_DWQI_1",
                "water qu_2": "27-Feb-08",
                "water qu_3": null,
                "water qu_4": null,
                "water qu_5": null,
                "water qu_6": 7.36,
                "water qu_7": null,
                "water qu_8": null,
                "water qu_9": 0.0,
                "water qu10": 355.0,
                "water qu11": 0.015,
                "water qu12": 3.87,
                "water qu13": 0.0,
                "water qu14": 3.23,
                "water qu15": 342.0,
                "water qu16": null,
                "water qu17": null,
                "water qu18": null,
                "water qu19": null,
                "water qu20": 0.85,
                "water qu21": 0.3,
                "water qu22": 0,
                "water qu23": 2020
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [494022.0, 1326178.0]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "WDB_ID": 2,
                "SRC_DATA": "RDI DWQI Database",
                "STD_WELL_I": "RDI_DWQI_2",
                "OTH_WELL_I": null,
                "PROVINCE": "Kampong Cham",
                "DISTRICT": "Batheay",
                "COMMUNE": "Batheay",
                "VILLAGE": "Batheay",
                "VILLAGE_ID": 3010102,
                "CONDITION": null,
                "CONT_NAME": null,
                "CONT_PHONE": null,
                "CONT_QUAL": null,
                "CONT_SECT": null,
                "FACILITY": "Unknown",
                "FACILITY_N": "Unknown",
                "OWNER_NAME": null,
                "OWNER_PHON": null,
                "WGS_E": 494090,
                "WGS_N": 1326303,
                "MSL_APPROX": 7,
                "WELL_TYPE": "Drilled Well",
                "DRI_END_DA": "01-Jan-08",
                "DRI_TOT_DE": 5.0,
                "PUMP_INSTA": "Unknown",
                "PUMP_TYPE": null,
                "PUMP_MODEL": null,
                "PUMP_INST_": null,
                "PUMP_DEP_M": null,
                "PUMP_YIEL_": null,
                "PUMP_RIS_M": null,
                "COORD_SRC": "DATABASE",
                "water qual": "RDI DWQI Database",
                "water qu_1": "RDI_DWQI_2",
                "water qu_2": "27-Feb-08",
                "water qu_3": null,
                "water qu_4": null,
                "water qu_5": null,
                "water qu_6": 6.11,
                "water qu_7": null,
                "water qu_8": null,
                "water qu_9": 0.0,
                "water qu10": 240.0,
                "water qu11": 0.075,
                "water qu12": 1.45,
                "water qu13": 0.18,
                "water qu14": 2.77,
                "water qu15": 128.0,
                "water qu16": null,
                "water qu17": null,
                "water qu18": null,
                "water qu19": null,
                "water qu20": 0.4,
                "water qu21": 0.1,
                "water qu22": 160,
                "water qu23": 36000
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [494090.0, 1326303.0]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I try may tool like ogr2ogr and any other online tool. and i get the same error :

using **ogr2ogr**:

ogr2ogr -f "KML" -overwrite "well.kml" "well2.GeoJSON" -T_SRS EPSG:4326

Error:

**ERROR 1: Latitude 1326178.000000 is invalid. Valid range is [-90,90]. This warning will not be issued any more
    Warning 1: Longitude 494022.000000 has been modified to fit into range [-180,180]. This warning will not be issued any more**

Comment: Error message is very clear: `Latitude 1326178.000000 is invalid`. It needs to be something like `13.26178` I think. I don't know if those tools have format setup for latitude, longitude values but my guess is you have to modify those values.

Comment: @alalp yes you may be right, there should be a tool. This data i got from this website url http://cambodiawellmap.com/worldbank/maps/44789/arsenic-contamination-by-well#. I see they use proj4j to convert xy to latlong. Do you have any idea how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have found solutions to solve my problem. There are many way for Coordinate system transformation depend on different coordinate system or cartographic projection.

**1- Use https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs**

This on-line tool allows you to insert value pairs of geographic coordinates and transform them to different coordinate system or cartographic projection. You can insert value pairs to the text area labeled as "Input coordinate pairs" - also by using copy/paste even from MS Excell or similar programs. This tool accepts various input formats of value pairs - only what you need is to have one pair by a row. Please see examples in the input text area window.

[image]

**2- Use [cs2cs](http://proj4.org/apps/cs2cs.html) command line (Note: I am using Ubuntu)**

cs2cs performs transformation between the source and destination cartographic coordinate system on a set of input points. The coordinate system transformation can include translation between projected and geographic coordinates as well as the application of datum shifts.

```
cs2cs +proj=utm +zone=48 +a=6377276.345 +b=6356075.41314024 +towgs84=198,881,317,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +to +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs  source.geojson > target.geojson
```

Example : [converting-coordinates-with-cs2cs](http://hannes.enjoys.it/blog/2015/07/converting-coordinates-with-cs2cs/)

**3- Use [Proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js)**

Proj4js is a JavaScript library to transform point coordinates from one coordinate system to another, including datum transformations. Originally a port of PROJ.4 and GCTCP C it is a part of the MetaCRS group of projects.

```
var firstProjection = '+proj=utm +zone=48 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs';
var secondProjection = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[494022.0, 1326178.0]);
```

Result:

```
[104.94123506418815, 11.999521158195288]
```

I Hope this could help other develop who faced the same problem as me.